# deleting range when closing workbook, xls vba

Tags: excel, vba

i'd like the range

```
Range("A2:G" & z)
```

to be deleted with closing the workbook - can someone please help my with the code?

thanks,
kay

this is what i tried:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Makro1()
    'insert clipboard
    Workbooks("Pfl_SchutzStat.xls").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    'insert formulas to look up sheet ZTAXLIST
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,ZTAXLIST!C2:C9,1)"
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,ZTAXLIST!C2:C9,3)"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,ZTAXLIST!C2:C9,4)"
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,ZTAXLIST!C2:C9,5)"
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,ZTAXLIST!C2:C9,6)"
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,ZTAXLIST!C2:C9,7)"
    'autofill formulas
    Dim z As Integer
    z = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    Range("B2:G2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:G" & z)
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

here i added the sub that should delete the range
i also tried to make it as to close the workbook without saving and without asking for it 
i tried to insert a msgbox - when closing it seems the macro is not called!

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ev As Boolean
    Dim datei As String
    Dim z As Integer
    z = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    datei = ThisWorkbook.Name
    ev = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False            
    If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Else
        Workbooks(datei).Saved = True
    Application.Quit
    End If
    Worksheets("Abfrage").Range("A2:G" & z).ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = ev
End Sub
```

Comment: Btw, you can accept answers from your previous questions if any fits to what you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event vba function *BeforeClose* : find more information here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220801%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Do not forget to point to the worksheet where you want to delete your lines.

Here is an example :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'delete the lines of the "Sheet1"
    Dim z As Integer
    z = 2   'or whatever depending on your previous code

    'replace "Sheet1" by the name of your sheet
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:G" & z).Delete Shift:=xlUp    
End Sub
```

-=EDIT=-

First, you don't need to select every cell before setting a formula. For instance you could do :

```
Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,ZTAXLIST!C2:C9,4)"
```

Instead of :

```
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,ZTAXLIST!C2:C9,4)"
```

Besides, did you put the Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) in the ThisWorkbook part in the VBA Editor ? It shouldn't be in a Module or a worksheet module !

Regards,

Max

Comment: Or, `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:G" & z).ClearContents`. I have a feeling the OP doesn't really want to delete the cells, but just erase what's in them.

Comment: thanks,i added "option explicit" and the proposed code in front of my macro. i am pointing at the worksheet and everything, but when i close nothing is deleted.. have i forgotten anything?

Comment: without the workbook, we cannot help you more. You can try to debug (put a break point in your code) and see the vars or put a msgbox in your code.

Comment: i added my full code to the original post - maybe one can see the error from there..

Comment: main problem was just to put Workbook before close to ThisWorkbook! Thanks a lot - worked oout finally..